# List comprehension on nested lists with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list

```
list1 = [ [2,3,4] ,[5,6,7] ,[1,5,8] ,[2,3,{'key1':12}] ]
```

From list1 I need to remove the list which has a dictionary element and generate list2 which should be [ [2,3,4] ,[5,6,7] ,[1,5,8] ]

with a for loop I can get the list2 like

```
for e1 in list1:
    condition = 0
    for e2 in e1:
        if type(e2) is dict:
            condition = 1
    if not condition:
        list2.append(e1)
```

How can I get the result for list2 with list comprehension?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
list1 = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [1, 5, 8], [2, 3, {"key1": 12}]]

list2 = [l for l in list1 if dict not in map(type, l)]
print(list2)
```

Prints:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [1, 5, 8]]
```

---

Or using `any()` (Thanks @chepner):

```py
list2 = [l for l in list1 if not any(isinstance(x, dict) for x in l)]
print(list2)
```

Comment: `... if not any(instanceof(x, dict) for x in l)` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for suggestion... I've added it.

Comment: yes it works. Thanks for the response.